# qemu-kvm start virt-viewer?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6

I recently installed qemu-kvm in Centos 6.3 x86_64.

I want to start a VM only with an iso file, so i typed:

```
qemu-kvm -hda file.iso -m 1024
```

but I only get

> VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5901

I tried appending '-vga std' to the command, but i cant get virt-viewer to start.

How can I get qemu-kvm to automatically start virt-viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qemu-kvm has no option to launch the viewer; you must do it manually:

```
 qemu-kvm -hda file.iso -m 1024 && virt-viewer ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply type in "virt-manager" in the shell. You should be able to connect to the local hypervisor (KVM) and have a view on the VM you just started.

You can also start the VM through virt-manager, btw.

Answer (score 0):

`qemu-kvm` has nothing to do with `virt-viewer`, which is a part of libvirt. virt-viewer can actually connect to VMs started through libvirt (using `virsh` or `virt-manager`), not directly via `qemu-kvm`. Of course there can be workarounds, but if you want to use virt-viewer, there should be no reason not to run your VMs via libvirt.